# hiding div in smarty

Tags: php, css, smarty

I have a smarty template setup and have multiple companies using company ids.  What I'm trying to do is have a if statement that shows a google map in a div if that company id is displayed else hide the div.  Here is the code so far but not sure what to put in the else to hide the div if company id doesn't equal 40

```
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            {if $companyID == 40}<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3338.0522766505114!2d-86.8171146!3d33.21272569999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88892f56c3e80995%3A0x436bc6444b3d4287!2s720+Fulton+Springs+Rd%2C+Alabaster%2C+AL+35007!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1429022619772" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>{else}{/if}
                        </div>
```

Comment: `display:none;`? Or did I mis-understand?

Answer (score 0):

like in php you can omit the `else` or `elseif` if it's not needed,
and if you want to eliminate div from markup wrap that into the if statement

```
{if $companyID eq 40}<div class="accordion-heading"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3338.0522766505114!2d-86.8171146!3d33.21272569999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88892f56c3e80995%3A0x436bc6444b3d4287!2s720+Fulton+Springs+Rd%2C+Alabaster%2C+AL+35007!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1429022619772" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>{/if}
```